# How do I access variable while looping through

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have this piece of code

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    // Returns current URL page.
    var currentURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + 
                     window.location.pathname + window.location.search 
    var market_table = document.getElementById("market_item_table");
    var market_table_cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var rowLength = market_table.rows.length;

    var items = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-item-id]')
    var j = 0;

    items.forEach(function(getItem) {
        var itemData = items[j].dataset;
        var tooltip = JSON.parse(itemData.tooltip)[0][0][0];
        console.log(tooltip);
        j++
    });

    for (var i = 1; i < rowLength; i++) {
        var oCells = market_table.rows.item(i).cells;
        console.log("Paka nr. " + i + "Nazwa przedmiotu: " + tooltip + ' ' + 
                     oCells[1].innerText + ' ' + oCells[2].innerText);
    }        
})();
```

Now how would I go about and get the value of variable tooltip every time it loops through the NodeList?

The bigger picture is that I want to assign the correct names to the correct items listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an array outside of the for loop that stores the values of the tooltips, then use it in a separate function:

```
var tooltips = [];
Items.forEach(function(getItem) {
    var itemData = getItem.dataset;
    var tooltip = JSON.parse(itemData.tooltip)[0][0][0];
    console.log(tooltip);
});

for (var i=0; i < rowlength... {
    // Do something with the tooltips
    console.log(tooltips[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, how does this help me exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I've modified the answer to show you how to access tooltips in the second loop.

Comment: Hi, I've tested it out and unfortunately it doesn't work it just returns undefined each time the loop runs, I tried using push to populate the array and it actually started showing results but for some reason the first result is still always "undefined" which messes up the order of the array.